# Unable to authenticate with jax-ws on Glassfish

Tags: java, glassfish, jax-ws, basic-authentication

I have been trying to create a java service that uses basic authentication over SSL.  Configuring the SSL was quite simple but configuring authentication is much more of a problem.  Any time I try to call a method marked with a @RolesAllowed annotation I receive the following exception...

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" javax.xml.ws.soap.SOAPFaultException: javax.ejb.EJBAccessException
at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.fault.SOAP11Fault.getProtocolException(SOAP11Fault.java:178)
at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.fault.SOAPFaultBuilder.createException(SOAPFaultBuilder.java:111)
at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.sei.SyncMethodHandler.invoke(SyncMethodHandler.java:108)
at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.sei.SyncMethodHandler.invoke(SyncMethodHandler.java:78)
at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.sei.SEIStub.invoke(SEIStub.java:129)
at $Proxy30.reverseString(Unknown Source)
at securitytestclient.SecurityTestClient.reverseStringSOAP(SecurityTestClient.java:305)
at securitytestclient.SecurityTestClient.buttonReverseActionPerformed(SecurityTestClient.java:217)
at securitytestclient.SecurityTestClient.access$000(SecurityTestClient.java:20)
at securitytestclient.SecurityTestClient$1.actionPerformed(SecurityTestClient.java:72)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2018)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2341)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener$Actions.actionPerformed(BasicButtonListener.java:303)
at javax.swing.SwingUtilities.notifyAction(SwingUtilities.java:1661)
at javax.swing.JComponent.processKeyBinding(JComponent.java:2879)
at javax.swing.JComponent.processKeyBindings(JComponent.java:2926)
at javax.swing.JComponent.processKeyEvent(JComponent.java:2842)
at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6282)
at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2229)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4861)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2287)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4687)
at java.awt.KeyboardFocusManager.redispatchEvent(KeyboardFocusManager.java:1890)
at java.awt.DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.dispatchKeyEvent(DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.java:752)
at java.awt.DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.preDispatchKeyEvent(DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.java:1017)
at java.awt.DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.typeAheadAssertions(DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.java:889)
at java.awt.DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.dispatchEvent(DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.java:717)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4731)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2287)
at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2713)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4687)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:707)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$000(EventQueue.java:101)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:666)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:664)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:87)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:680)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:678)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:677)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:211)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:128)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:117)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:113)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:90)
```

My server is using JavaEE on Glassfish 3.  It's functions are defined in a bean as follows...

```
package com.intproimp.testing.beans;

import javax.annotation.security.PermitAll;
import javax.annotation.security.RolesAllowed;
import javax.ejb.Local;
import javax.ejb.Stateless;

@Stateless(mappedName="ejb/StringOps/Bean")
@Local(StringOps.class)
public class StringOpsBean implements StringOps {

    @PermitAll
    @Override
    public String echoString(String str) {
        return str;
    }

    @RolesAllowed({"admin"})
    @Override
    public String reverseString(String str) {
        char[] input = str.toCharArray();
        char[] output = new char[input.length];
        for (int i = 0; i < output.length; i++) {
            output[i] = input[input.length - i - 1];
        }
        return new String(output);
    }
}
```

I have added the login config to my web.xml file...

```
<login-config>
    <auth-method>BASIC</auth-method>
    <realm-name>testing-frealm</realm-name>
</login-config>
<security-role>
    <description/>
    <role-name>admin</role-name>
</security-role>
<security-role>
    <description/>
    <role-name>user</role-name>
</security-role>
```

The security realm is just a file realm with one user(name: "andrew", pass: "12345").
I've also added the role-group mappings to my glassfish-web.xml

```
<security-role-mapping>
    <role-name>user</role-name>
    <group-name>user</group-name>
</security-role-mapping>
<security-role-mapping>
    <role-name>admin</role-name>
    <group-name>admin</group-name>
</security-role-mapping>
```

On the client side, I have a simple swing application to test from...

[image: Swing Test Application]

The call being made is to the reverse function on a SOAP channel.  The SOAP client components are generated with NetBeans via the New->WebService Client function.  And the action associated with the reverse button click is...

```
private void addAuthenticateionSOAP(StringOpsSOAP port) {
    ((BindingProvider) port).getRequestContext().put(BindingProvider.USERNAME_PROPERTY, fieldUsername.getText());
    ((BindingProvider) port).getRequestContext().put(BindingProvider.PASSWORD_PROPERTY, fieldPassword.getText());
}

private String reverseStringSOAP(String str) {
    StringOpsSOAP_Service service = new StringOpsSOAP_Service();
    StringOpsSOAP port = service.getStringOpsSOAPPort();
    if (checkAuthentication.isSelected()) addAuthenticateionSOAP(port);
    return port.reverseString(str);
}
```

I'm sure there is just some little thing that I'm missing, but I've been looking at the problem for days and still haven't found it.

-- Edit -- 
I realized there might be some confusion since I didn't post my WebService code.  The EJB that contains the String functions is accessed through a SOAP WebService Bean...

```
package com.intproimp.test.web;

import com.intproimp.test.beans.StringOps;
import javax.ejb.EJB;
import javax.jws.WebService;
import javax.ejb.Stateless;
import javax.jws.WebMethod;
import javax.jws.WebParam;

@WebService(serviceName = "StringOpsSOAP")
@Stateless()
public class StringOpsSOAP {

    @EJB
    private StringOps ops;

    @WebMethod(operationName = "echoString")
    public String echoString(@WebParam(name = "str") String str) {
        return ops.echoString(str);
    }

    @WebMethod(operationName = "reverseString")
    public String reverseString(@WebParam(name = "str") String str) {
        return ops.reverseString(str);
    }
}
```

Comment: Perhaps, Glassfish is doing some magic, but I would not expect that: you have published your service and EJB, but calling it as SOAP WS. You have either to call it as remote EJB (and follow the authentication game in EJB world) or publish your WS using JSR-181 annotations (see [example](https://community.jboss.org/wiki/JBWS181HelloWorld)), namely `@WebService` on implementation class and `@WebMethod` on each method in each method you want to publish as SOAP. P.S. Interesting to look into `EJBAccessException` you've got.

Comment: I should clarify, the EJB is used by a Web Service annotated class.  I'll edit my question to add it's code.

Comment: Have you been able to solve this issue?

Comment: Have you tried enabling an audit module to have all authentication attemps logged to server.log ? It would really be helpful to you, I think.

Answer (score 2):

You need to add a `<security-constraint>` to your `web.xml` which describes who is allowed to access a certain URL. It's described in [Securing Web Applications](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gkbaa.html) in the **Java EE 6 Tutorial**. In your case it should be something like this:

```
<security-constraint>  
<display-name>WebServiceSecurity</display-name>  

<web-resource-collection>  
    <web-resource-name>Authorized users only</web-resource-name>  
    <url-pattern>/yoururl</url-pattern>  
    <http-method>POST</http-method>
</web-resource-collection>  

<auth-constraint>       
    <role-name>user</role-name>
    <role-name>admin</role-name>
</auth-constraint>
```

Edit: This should do the trick if you have make your stateless session bean a web service, by adding the `@webservice` annotation to the class and publishing the methods using `@webmethod`, as dma_k said in comments.

Edit 2:
From the link above:

> **Specifying Security Constraints**
>
> A security constraint is used to define the access privileges to a collection of resources using their URL mapping.

Further on:

> **Specifying a Web Resource Collection**
>
> *url-pattern* is used to list the request URI to be protected. Many applications have both unprotected and protected resources. **To provide unrestricted access to a resource, do not configure a security constraint for that particular request URI.**

And:

> **Specifying an Authorization Constraint**
>
> An authorization constraint establishes a requirement for authentication and names the roles authorized to access the URL patterns and HTTP methods declared by this security constraint. **If there is no authorization constraint, the container must accept the request without requiring user authentication.**

So, no `<security-constraint>` => no authentication => no roles available.

Use auditing or read info (`getUserPrincipal()`, `isUserInRole()`) from `WebServiceContext`, to verify this.

Comment: The @RolesAllowed annotation that is on StringOpsBean.reverseString(String) does effectively block access to that method call.  The issue is that Glassfish doesn't appear to accept a user login.

Comment: @AndrewRademacher You want to restrict access to that method. To do so, you need to specify a security constraint. Without it, no authentication is required. Without authentication, there are no user roles and that's why no user is granted access to the method. BTW: Activating auditing really helped me when setting up security.

Comment: So if I were to add a constraint that had a path of /* and it's role was user.  Then would the @RolesAllowed({"admin"}) just stack on top of that?  So to call reverseString you would have to be both a user and an admin?

Comment: Not quite. Using the `<security-constraint>`, you specify that a certain resource requires authentication and which roles are allowed to access that resource. The `@RolesAllowed` annotation allows for finer grained access control. So you would specify admin and user roles within the constrain, meaning users from both roles can access the web service. Which method is available to each role, is controlled using `@RolesAllowed`.

Comment: @AndrewRademacher: I agree with you, you don't need `<security-constraint>`: roles should be checked at entry point of the method, not at URL level. In your case what perhaps is not working is the role **delegation** from WebService to EJB. WebService will check the role from `HttpServletRequest`, but EJB... Perhaps it does not know about any Web context and expects the user to be provided in EJB call. I might be wrong here. Can you debug AS and put a breakpoint on creation of `javax.ejb.EJBAccessException`?

Comment: @TPete: But how to separate restricted and non-restricted operations for WebService, supposing it is deployed to `/mycontext/myservice`?

Comment: @dma_k Using the security annotations from JSR 250: `@PermitAll` grants access to everyone, `@DeclareRoles` and `@RolesAllowed` are used for role based access control. I found this [article](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/J2EE/security_annotation/) very useful.

Comment: I also hit that article recently, thanks. I want `/url-pattern` to be accessed also by non-authenticated users. But how such user will pass WebContainer `<auth-constraint>`, if it is specified that `user` or `admin` can only access the given `/url-pattern`? The request will not even arrive to WS (to check against `@PermitAll`). Let me know, if I am wrong.

Comment: @dma_k As far as I know, this is not possible. You will have to use separate endpoints/URLs, in that scenario.

Comment: I've tried just securing the StringOpsSOAP resource with a number of string path's, but I've been unable in any instance including "/*", been able to deny access to the StringOps bean at all.  Even clients that don't attempt to authenticate at all can make calls to the StringOpsSOAP resource.