# How to have @RunAs work in a @Webservice without principal?

Tags: java, web-services, jakarta-ee, glassfish, jax-ws

I'm trying to have a `@WebService` declared in Glassfish be able to call an EJB which requires user to be in a given role. For now, my WebService has no authentication (and I doubt I will add it soon).

Security considerations aside (I perfectly know it's not the better way to do things, thanks), as I have no logged in user, my `WebServiceContext` alays tell me `context.isUserInRole("importer")` althgouth my @WebService is also annotated with `@RunAs("importer")`.

How can I make that work ? (without adding security to my web-service, of course).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out error was not the expected one.

My `glassfish-web.xml` was not correct, since it was

```
<security-role-mapping>
    <role-name>guest</role-name>
    <principal-name>guest</principal-name>
    <group-name>users</group-name>
</security-role-mapping>
```

It seems that, encountering such config, Glassfish creates a principal containing only group specification, and not principal. As a consequence, I removed the `group-name` line, and all worked OK. My `glassfish-web.xml` now contains

```
<security-role-mapping>
    <role-name>guest</role-name>
    <principal-name>guest</principal-name>
</security-role-mapping>
```

Comment: You have removed `<principal-name>` don't you?

Comment: May I ask you to leave a comment on [Unable to authenticate with jax-ws on Glassfish](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9774236)? Your opinion would be very valuable.

Comment: @dma_k I fixed my answer to be a little more clear. Concerning the question you redirected me to, I guess there is some authentication denial that is not logged by glassfish. As a consequence, I added a comment to enable one audit module.