# Call a secured remote ejb deployed in glassfish from a Java client application

Tags: java, glassfish, ejb

I'm trying to call a secured remote ejb who's deployed in glassfish from a simple client application but I can't authenticate myself.

The client:

```
    public void go() {
    try {
        Context ctx = getInitialContext();
        TestBeanRemote remote = (TestBeanRemote) ctx.lookup("java:global/ejbTest2/TestBean");
        String result = remote.testMe();
        System.out.println(result);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

private Context getInitialContext() throws NamingException, FileNotFoundException, IOException {
    Properties p = new Properties();
    InputStream stream = Runner.class.getResourceAsStream("jndi.properties");
    assert stream != null : "jndi.properties file not found";
    p.load(stream);
    return new InitialContext(p);
}
```

jndi.properties on the client

```
java.naming.factory.initial = com.sun.enterprise.naming.SerialInitContextFactory
java.naming.factory.url.pkgs = com.sun.enterprise.naming
java.naming.factory.state = com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.JNDIStateFactoryImpl
#optional. Defaults to localhost. Only needed if web server is running
#on a different host than the appserver
org.omg.CORBA.ORBInitialHost = localhost
#optional. Defaults to 3700. Only needed if target orb port is not 3700.
org.omg.CORBA.ORBInitialPort = 3700
java.naming.security.principal = test
java.naming.security.credentials = test
```

EJB

```
@Stateless(description = "A simple bean to learn the ins and outs of ejbs")
@DeclareRoles({ Roles.ADMIN, Roles.USER })
@RolesAllowed({})
public class TestBean implements TestBeanRemote {

    @Resource
    private SessionContext ejbContext;

    @Override
    @RolesAllowed(Roles.ADMIN)
    // @PermitAll
    public String testMe() throws Exception {
        return ejbContext.getCallerPrincipal().getName();
    }
}
```

sun-ejb-jar

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE sun-ejb-jar PUBLIC "-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD Application Server 9.0 EJB 3.0//EN" "http://www.sun.com/software/appserver/dtds/sun-ejb-jar_3_0-0.dtd">
<sun-ejb-jar>
    <security-role-mapping>
        <role-name>Admin</role-name>
        <group-name>Admin</group-name> <!-- As defined in container -->
    </security-role-mapping>
    <security-role-mapping>
        <role-name>User</role-name>
        <group-name>User</group-name> <!-- As defined in container -->
    </security-role-mapping>
    <enterprise-beans />
</sun-ejb-jar>
```

And I've added User Id "test" credentials "test" Group List "Admin" in the administration console in Configurations > default-config > Security > Realms > file > Manage users

This results in a stacktrace containing org.omg.CORBA.NO_PERMISSION and ejbContext.getCallerPrincipal().getName() results to "Anonymous" when I use PermitAll

What am I missing over here?

Comment: This might help: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9774236/unable-to-authenticate-with-jax-ws-on-glassfish/9783431#9783431](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9774236/unable-to-authenticate-with-jax-ws-on-glassfish/9783431#9783431)

Answer (score 2):

This thread is old but answer might help someone. The principal & credentials in Context are ignored. Before ejb lookup you need to use ProgrammaticLogin to access the EJB.

```
System.setProperty("java.security.auth.login.config", "auth.conf");

ProgrammaticLogin pl = new ProgrammaticLogin();
pl.login("user", "password");

//Now lookup the EJB and then logout

pl.logout();
```

As you can see you need to set the "java.security.auth.login.config", which points to a file, the contents of while shoule be

```
default {
com.sun.enterprise.security.auth.login.ClientPasswordLoginModule required debug=false; };
```

This says that you want to use the default realm configured on server or you can also explicitly specify the realm by replacing "default" with the realm name for example "file"

Comment: I am still getting `ANONYMOUS` on glassfish, however i have successfully authenticated on client side.